# Web API 2 can't scaffold controller from stored procedure based model

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I can create models based on tables in my database and then scaffold a Web API 2 controller with actions using Entity Framework (6) successfully. However, if the model has been created based on a stored procedure I can't create the Web API 2 controller. I get the error message:

There was an error running the selected code generator. Unable to retrieve metadata for ....

I've tried several stored procedures, each with the same result. I have also tried creating the ODATA version of the Web API 2 controller with actions and received the same result.

The stored procedures return a record set.

How do I resolve, or workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The dbContext generated should have the stored proc wrapper generated that looks like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<uspStoredProcName_Result> uspStoredProcName(string abc)
{
     ...
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<uspStoredProcName_Result_Result>("uspStoredProcName_Result", abcParameter);
}
```

Then in your code, you will call it like this:

```
var abcResults = dbContext.uspStoredProcName(abc).ToList();
```

Make sure you selected the stored procedure when you generate the models (DbContext)

Comment: Yes, the dbcontext has the wrapper you mentioned.
public virtual ObjectResult<uspGetEmployeeManagers_Result> uspGetEmployeeManagers(Nullable<int> businessEntityID)
        {
            var businessEntityIDParameter = businessEntityID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("BusinessEntityID", businessEntityID) :
                new ObjectParameter("BusinessEntityID", typeof(int));
    
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<uspGetEmployeeManagers_Result>("uspGetEmployeeManagers", businessEntityIDParameter);
        }

Comment: So how are you calling the proc?

Comment: The issue is fixed now. I think the scaffolding wont work for the stored procedures. So, I created an empty Web Api controller and used the following code:

public IHttpActionResult Get(int Id)
{
    dbEntities db = new dbdbEntities();
    var record = db.uspStoreProcedure(Id);

    if (record == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(record);
}

Comment: try to have a look there: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-stored-procedure-scaffolding-utillity-for-netcore3/